# SenTestKit: cleaning up after ALL tests have run?

Tags: unit-testing, xcode, ocunit

I am using SenTest in XCode for my unit tests. I must run a command-line task for my unit tests to test. I can do that in the +initialize method of my test class (subclass of SenTestCase, of course).

I would like to terminate the command-line task when the tests are done. Since there's not an opposite of +initialize, I'm stumped.

Is there some way to subclass a SenTest class to do this that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Don't run your command-line tool in +initialize.  That's sent by the Objective-C runtime when the class is first sent *any* message.

Instead, run your command-line tool in your test's `+setUp` method.  (Note that I really did mean `+setUp` and not `-setUp`; lots of folks seem to be a bit fuzzy on the difference between class and instance methods.)

In this case, a **class** `setUp` method is invoked by OCUnit before **any** of tests in a `SenTestCase` subclass are run, and a **class** `tearDown` method is invoked by OCUnit after **all** tests in a `SenTestCase` subclass ar run.

So the overall flow for a particular `SenTestCase` subclass is:

- send `+setUp` to `SomeTestCase`
- for each `test` method starting in `SomeTestCase` (call it `test___`)

  - create a new instance of `SomeTestCase`
  - send `-setUp` to it
  - send `-test___` to it
  - send `-tearDown` to it
  - release it
- send `+tearDown` to `SomeTestCase`

This way if you have something that needs to be done before any of your `-test` methods run, or something that needs to be done after all of your `-test` methods run, there's a deterministic point at which you can make that happen.  (Rather than rely on memory management, which isn't deterministic in the same way, and may not be deterministic at all if you're using GC.)

Comment: I hadn't found anything that talked about the +setUp/+teardown methods. Thank you for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [Google Toolbox for Mac](http://code.google.com/p/google-toolbox-for-mac/) or its further derivative [GHUnit](http://github.com/gabriel/gh-unit). Both (I think) provide class-level setup and teardown at least. If you really want to run a command-line before all tests are run and then a second command line (perhaps to kill the first) after tests are run, I would modify the shell script build phase that runs the unit tests (the last step in a UnitTest bundle target's build phases).

Comment: You don't need any additional frameworks to have class-level setup and teardown; these are part of OCUnit.