# How do I realize setup() and teardown() before each unit test in the Objective-C Xcode bundle?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, unit-testing, tdd, installation

I am new to Objective-C and I am trying to start right away with TestDrivenDevelopment, since I find it really assuring, when at least the *tests* do pass.

Before that I made some Tutorials in Java where I got a little understanding for TDD. [Brett Schucherts Video-Tutorials](http://vimeo.com/album/205252) where he goes step by step through coding a full RPNCalculator is a gold mine to learn the stuff by watching him in action.

To reduce code duplication there is for instance this nice thing where you do:

```
@Before
public void init() {
    /* Stuff that which will be set up before the call of each test method/*
}
```

which is then called before each test you have in your TestClass in Java.

This I want to realize in Objective-C + Xcode. I should mention, that I am using Xcode 4.3 (latest version) and that I am using the built in TestFramework.

The only thing I found in the web that came near what I am looking for was [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3641897/641514).

Unfortunately I am not able to reproduce the described way of doing things. A minimal runnable example and/or a more detailed explanation for a Newcomer would would be awesome and well appreciated!

By the way, sorry for the bad english. Still learning the language. :-)

**Edit:**

Here is a minimal example which does not work. Perhaps someone can tell me what is wrong. Xcode seems not to be able to recognize `board` inside the body of the test methods.

```
#import <SenTestingKit/SenTestingKit.h>
@interface ABoardShould : SenTestCase
@end

#import "ABoardShould.h"
@implementation ABoardShould

- (void)setUp
{
    [super setUp];

    int rowCount = 6;
    int columnCount = 7;
    Board *board = [[Board alloc] initWithShapeRowCount:rowCount andColumnCount:columnCount];
}

- (void)tearDown
{
    // Tear-down code here.

    [super tearDown];
}

- (void)testHaveItsShapeSetWhenInitialised {
    STAssertEquals([board rowCount], rowCount, @"");
    STAssertEquals([board columnCount], columnCount, @"");
}

- (void)testHaveTheDimensionsOfItsBoardMatchTheGivenShape {        
    NSMutableArray *expectedFields = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:columnCount*rowCount];
    for(int i=0; i < (rowCount*columnCount); i++) [expectedFields addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInt: 0]];

    STAssertEquals([expectedFields count], [[board fields] count], @"");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setup and teardown methods of your test case class must be called `setUp` and `tearDown`.  This is described in [*Xcode Unit Testing Guide: Writing Test Case Methods*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/UnitTesting/03-Writing_Test_Case_Methods/writing_tests.html).

In your example, `board` is a local variable in the `setUp` method.  You need to make it an instance variable.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I posted an example above that should explain where my problems are, since I still didn't manage to get it to work.